# operand type clash datetime2 is incompatible with tinyint in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Migrated the MSAccess database to SQL server. All necessary update were made to point the queries and tables to new SQL server. Now, when I open a form I getting the "**operand type clash datetime2 is incompatible with tinyint**". Can anyone know how to fix this?

I already tried `BETWEEN` and still got the same error

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW
       [Overall query].Project,
       [Overall query].Complete,
       [Overall query].[Lot #],
       [Overall query].[Lot qty],
       [Overall query].[dbo_Visual table].[Actual S/S],
       [Overall query].[dbo_Visual table].[No of reject],
       [Overall query].[dbo_Testing table].[Actual S/S],
       [Overall query]. [dbo_Testing table].[No of reject],
       [Overall query].[Lot accept ( final )],
       [Overall query].[Lot reject ( final )],
       [Overall query].[FQA II],
       [Overall query].[FQA III]
FROM [Overall query]
WHERE ((([Overall query].Complete)>="&Forms![Status form]![Start Date]&"
  AND ([Overall query].Complete)<="&Forms![Status form]![End Date]&"
  AND ([Overall query].Complete)=True)
  AND (([Overall query].[Lot #]) Like '%1')
  AND (([Overall query].[FQA II])=False)
  AND (([Overall query].[FQA III])=False))
ORDER BY [Overall query].Project, [Overall query].Complete;
```

I think the problem is in this where condition

```
[Overall query].Complete)>="&Forms![Status form]![Start Date]&" And ([Overall query].Complete)<="&Forms![Status form]![End Date]&"
```

Comment: You've tagged MySQL and SQL Server and mentioned MS Access in your title. What are you *really* using here. `datetime2` is a SQL Server data type; not MS Access or MySQL.

Comment: Now that I've added some formatting to your query though (good use of whitespace in any language is a must), you can see the *real* problem is that you are injecting the value. Write your SQL properly and parametrise your statement and this problem very likely doesn't exist.

Comment: This same query worked before migration? This is a saved query object? Why would this be RecordSource for a form? - it is a non-editable dataset.

Comment: @Larnu - Yes the correct tag is SQL server and MSAccess. When i put it on that format it will have an error on the fields saying "invalid recordsource property" and "missing fields". The user needs to input the date to retrieve the data. Sorry I'm that to familiar with MSAccess still learning how about it.

Comment: @June7, Yes it is the same query i just updated the query tables and its working before i migrated it. Not saved query object and yes it was on the record source property. What do you mean by non-editable dataset? It is my first time to use MSAccess and just need to migrate the database to SQL server.

Comment: Correction, DISTINCT results in a non-editable dataset. Apparently data can still be edited in a DISTINCTROW query. I've never needed DISTINCTROW. Why are the form references enclosed in quote marks? Why using & characters? I don't see how that syntax could have worked before.

Comment: @June7 I forgot to delete & character.

`WHERE ((([Overall query].Complete)>=Forms![Status form]![Start Date]
  AND ([Overall query].Complete)<= Forms![Status form]![End Date]`

That how it looks previously then after migrating the database but I having an error **ODBC call Failed**. So what I did is add the &.

Comment: Do you need the additional accuracy of DateTime2? Could you make the field just Date type?

Answer (score 0):

Before you play with the query, open up the linked table in design view (access client).

If the DateTime2 column is seen as a text/string column as opposed to Date/time, then you have two choices here:

Install + use the native 11 or later driver for your linked tables. SSMA by default uses the newer datetime2 as defaults when migrating to Access. However, the standard legacy built in SQL driver used to link tables does NOT support datetime2, and linked tables will show these columns as a string (and hence you type error).

If you don't want to go to the pain of installing the native 11 (or later ODBC) driver, then if you only have say 1 or 2 tables, then from the sql studio change the datetime2 columns to a datetime column (and re-link your tables).

So the standard SQL driver does not support datetime2 columns. You can also during a SSMA migration change the default to use datetime as opposed to datetime2. So, which ever comes out for you as less work, you have to:

a) re-migrate the data and ensure that datetime2 is not used.
b) open up with sql studio and change any datetime2 to a datetime column.
c) install the native 11 or later drivers on the workstation, and re-link, and thus access will now correctly see datetime2 columns as date/time.